# Add the same domain user account to two Azure AD Domains

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have access to two different Azure AD domains (a.com and b.com)  In both domains I have a local account (me@a.com and me@b.com).  What i'd really like to do use me@a.com to sign into both domains.

I know from reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-create-users-external that it is possible to do so but the caveat is:

```
You can select a user in another directory only if you're also a member of that directory.
```

I can't see how this is performed however - does this mean I need a Microsoft Account in both domains (as these aren't domain specific) to be able to insert the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [B2B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-what-is-azure-ad-b2b) for this scenario.

First add the user me@a.com to the tenant b.com: [How do Azure Active Directory admins add B2B collaboration users?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-admin-add-users)

Then assign a role to that user: [Grant permissions to users from partner organizations in your Azure Active Directory tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-b2b-add-guest-to-role)